# Windows Server 2012 - unable to create trust

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

I'm kinda having a hard time figuring out what caused the issue I'm having. So I have the following DC Servers:

- astro.local (192.168.1.50) (hostname: Server01)
- test.local (192.168.1.55)  (hostname: Server02)

So on the Server01 I created a stub zone and added test.local. On Server02, I did the same and added astro.local. Then I did "Transfer from zone" on both servers respectively and I can see it properly on DNS manager. Now the issue is that whenever I try to create a trust on either servers, I'm getting this error "The name you specified is not a valid windows domain trust". I'm not sure what to look for. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why you transferred the DNS zones in the first place. What ate you trying to accomplish? What name did you enter that's resulting in the error?

Comment: Hi, I did transfer zone to ensure that even if I am able to resolve the fqdn, I will be able to get the data (NS,etc) properly. By the way, on astro.local when I try to add a "New Trust", I'm putting in test.local or the fqdn, server01.test.local but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense do you probably have some fundamental things completely wrong. Astro.local and test.local are not server names and do not have specific IP addresses. Those are domain names, or at least should be. Your server names are server.astro.local or server.test.local and those resolve to specific IP address. The domain name itself resolves to any random domain controller on the domain. Your question really doesn’t make any sense right now.

Comment: Sorry, yah I just realize. I edited my original post :) both of them are dc servers on their own.